# fulfillmentText vs fulfillmentMessages in DialogFlow

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-hangouts

I am making a Chatbot which is using Google Hangout Chat currently, but will be ported on other chat platforms.
The chat code is handled on a Node.js backend and the Intent identification is done using DialogFlow's Nodejs API.

The Hangout Chat Response is as following:

```
{
  thread: {
    name: thread.name
  },
  text: 'The response in text',
  cards:['List of cards to show data']
}
```

The data is working fine, but I am stuck at parsing the response I get from DialogFlow and deciding on the `text` property of the response. There're two options to choose to send as the `text` property. One is `queryResult.fulfillmentText` which is just a string and easy to assign to the `text` property, while another is `queryResult.fulfillmentMessages` which is an array of objects containing the same text somewhere. This is what it looks like in my case:

```
"fulfillmentText": "We could find few matching products based on your query",
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "We could find few matching products based on your query"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "2nd text"
      ]
    }
  }
],
```

My question is what should I use between `fulfillmentText` and `fulfillmentMessages`? Also what are the differences between both of them. Why there're multiple texts/messages, given that Hangout Chat expects just one text response?

PS: I am using DialogFlow V2 API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this from the [Dialogflow Docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request)

> - fulfillmentText (String)  Text to be pronounced to the user or shown on the screen.
> - fulfillmentMessages (Object)    Collection of [rich messages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#message) to show the user.

So I should be using `fulfillmentText` to be sent as the `text` property of Hangout Chat response. `fulfillmentMessages` is for the **"Rich Messages"** such as Cards which I am anyway generating from my database.

Comment: I'm struggling with similar situation with V2 apis. did you get our fullfilmentMessages:[] working? here is my situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959535/dialogflow-v2-api-cards-not-shown-in-the-simulator.. appreciate any help

Comment: I don't use fullfilmentMessages. I am using the cards directly for Hangout Chat API. As far as I can see, google assistant and hangout chat have different acceptable format for rich messages such as cards.